# Documentation for Mongoose's on() method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't see find any documentation for Mongoose's on() method.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('open', () => {
   console.log('Connected to the MongoDB database.')
})
db.on('error', (err) => {
   console.log(`Database error: ${err}`);
});
```

In this sample code they provided 'open' for when the database connection is opened, and 'error' for connection errors, etc...   I also see other examples providing 'connected' and 'disconnected' as parameters to the on() method.   When would I use 'open' vs 'connected'?  What other options exist besides these???  Where are these parameters defined?  How does this on() method work exactly???

They're API docs give some cheap examples:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

I know this might seem like a simple question, but its quite frustrating to not get clear definitions in an API spec.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a jQuery method?

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp

It appears the event definitions are to be defined by the author of the jQuery object.  The Mongoose docs loosely define a few of these events here:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-readyState

But nowhere do they mention events such as 'open' and 'error'.

Answer (score 0):

These are nodeJS mongodb driver events. You can [find more information here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Db.html#event:authenticated) under the events section.

They are part of the `Db` class and are just surfaced by mongoose which you can see in the [mongoose source code as well](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/8b2a4993993bc5c81627889b9f5bb77e5629d95b/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js#L114).

Another article you might find useful in regards to the [mongoose connection events](http://davin.ninja/mongoose-connection-events-reconnecting-mongodb/).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late contribution, but I just noticed at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-db that connection() inherits from the NodeJS EventEmitter.  Its documentation (https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/the-nodejs-event-emitter/) talks about the on() method briefly (and also mentions once(), which I had also been wondering about).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32656547)